# how to overload methods with different parameter types in C#

Tags: c#, overloading

I'm trying to overload a method in C# with the same number of parameters but different types.

```
private double scale(double value) 
{
    return value * 100 / scale;
}

private float scale(float value)
{
    return value * 100 / scale;
}
```

but I get this error

> Error 4   The type '[className]' already
>   contains a definition for 'scale'

NOTE: I'm working in MVS 2008

Thank you.

Comment: Where did the scale variable in your divisors come from?  Is it a class member? Seeing a bit more of the class would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense:

`return value * 100 / scale;`

If you have a method name `scale`, then what does the `scale` at the end of the line do?

Your Method Signature is semantically correct, as this is perfectly legal C# code:

```
private float scale(float input)
{
    return input;
}

private double scale(double input)
{
    return input;
}
```

It seems that you also have a field or property named `scale` in your class:

`private float scale = 0.15f;`

Comment: +1 Good call. I need to get better at reading all of the code posted (I didn't see different input types and I missed the use of scale in the method itself...Doh!).

Comment: @Justin the tricky bit here is the code that is not posted, aka the field `scale` that has to exist for the error to make sense :)

Comment: yeah that was exactly my problem.
I have a global variable called scale. 
I changed it to scaleValue, that fixed it.
thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

To me it's complaining about the scale that you are using as a variable. 
You can have something like this

```
    private double scale1 =  0.0d;
    private double scale(double value)
    {
        return value * 100 / scale1;
    }

    private float scale(float value)
    {
        return (float) (value * 100 / scale1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that you are calling a member variable the same as a method?

```
float scale2;
private double scale(double value)
{
    return value * 100 / scale2;
}

private float scale(float value)
{
    return value * 100 / scale2;
}
```

This compiles, however you probably want the same return type.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to give you trouble. If the argument is, for example, `1.5`, how will the compiler know if you are passing a `float` or a `double`?

I would just stick with `double` unless you have special needs here.

Comment: "How does the compiler know" - because `1.5` *is* a double to the compiler. `1.5f` would be float. To the point, integer literals infer as integers, decimal literals as doubles. If you want a `long` or a `float` (or `decimal`), you would need a suffix (L, f, or m, as the case may be).

Comment: `1.5` is interpreted as double. If you want it to be a float, write `1.5f` or `float f = 1.5` to trigger an implicit conversion. So no ambiguity on the compiler side.

Comment: If you called these functions ScaleDouble and ScaleFloat, then you can pass 1.5f to both of them without any casting or warning. So if they both have the same name, which would the compiler call?

Comment: @sgmoore: The compiler would apply the "betterness" algorithm documented in the C# specification. In your particular example, an exact match is always better than an inexact match, so the "float" one would be called. If there was an inexact match and both were applicable then the "more specific" version would be called. Since every Giraffe is an Animal but not every Animal is a Giraffe, Giraffe is more specific. Since every float is convertible to double but not every double is convertible to float, float is more specific and the float version would be chosen.

Comment: @Michael: No ambiguity on the compiler side, no. But there is easily confusion on the developers side.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, that is correct. The specific phrasing you used was "how will the compiler know," which (in this case) is well defined. "How will the developer know," of course, is a different question and depends upon the awareness of said developer.

Comment: @Jonathan Very true, especially because of the implicit conversion. As useful as implicit conversions are, they can cause a LOT of confusion and late-night debug sessions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generics.

```
private T scale<T>(T value) where T: struct
{
    return value * 100 / scale;
}
```

You can replace `T` with float or double or any struct.